# Fill button into a datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a data grid and for the column *HCode* I have/need buttons, but the property *Code* can be null/empty in which case the Button will not be visible. 
I'd like to know if there are options or defining a mouse-click handler for the cell is the way to go.

Below is the DataGridTemplate defining the column

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="HCode" MinWidth="120">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Code}"
                                Style="{StaticResource BStyle}"
                                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=Background}"
                                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                        <!--Visibility="{qc:Binding '$P != null &amp;&amp; $P.Length > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding Code}}"-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Below is the style that is used

```
                <Style x:Key="BStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                    Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define two `DataTriggers`. Try this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Code}"
        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=Background}"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Code}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Code.Length}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Or:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Code.Length, FallbackValue=0}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```